# sorting an ArrayList of Objects by Property

Tags: java, android, arraylist, collections

I am trying to sort an ArrayList but getting this error. I want to understand this error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.pepperairport, PID: 8593
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.pepperairport.-$$Lambda$rvEnEZZsrxpHf9nk_9ENCmpa4qM
        at com.example.pepperairport.MainFragment$FlightQueryTask.onPostExecute(MainFragment.java:210)
        at com.example.pepperairport.MainFragment$FlightQueryTask.onPostExecute(MainFragment.java:180)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:651)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:668)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5875)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:749)
```

**And the line 210 is:**

```
 Collections.sort(flightTmp, Comparator.comparing(Flight::getDiff_time));
```

How can I sort this ArrayList?

Comment: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError This exception indicates that the JVM looked in its internal class definition data structure for the definition of a class and did not find it. This is different than saying that it could not be loaded from the classpath.

Comment: This looks like some code Instrumentation is going on, by a tool incompatible with lambda expressions.

Comment: how to overcome with this error? any idea ?

Comment: @Holger Any idea ,how to get rid of this error. This works perfectly fine if I run on emulator

Comment: I don’t know which tool is responsible. All I can see in your question, are the results of it, i.e. the `-wrap1` method which has a non-standard name and no line number(s) and the `-$$Lambda$rvEnEZZsrxpHf9nk_9ENCmpa4qM` class name which also differs from typical generated lambda class names by the prepended hyphen, which suggests that the same tool did manipulate it.